# is it impossible to parse this query statement in c++?

Tags: parsing

String values = L"’Bob, and Tom''s’, 1, ‘2013-03-19’";

I tried to parse this statement in cpp but it still has error.
This is the SQL statement. 
It is different '' and ".

I wonder that is it difficult or dangerous to parse the query statement not in SQLengine?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to parse a SQL statement without a precise SQL grammar *for the DB engine you are using* and strong parsing technology. Anything else you attempt to do will be buggy in its ability to parse, and thus in its ability to deliver practical value.

Yes, you can do that in C++ if you are determined enough.  I've met very few people that are that determined.  The fact that you are asking this question hints pretty strongly which camp you are in.